# Why are my JPG's not showing? (recovering JPG's from a .raw to current directory)

Tags: copy, jpeg, recover

I have been working for 3 weeks to try and get this thing working, but it just won't. I am trying to 'recover' **JPG's** from a .raw file by reading 512 bytes at a time and checking if the JPG begins with the 2 possible JPG beginnings. I got it to sorta-work: it shows the .jpg file in my file manager, but when I open it it says that it is the wrong **JPEG** start!? Why? I am just really frustrated. I honestly cannot see anything wrong. I even took the care to make it the same beginning! Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you for all your help!

```
    /**
 * recover.c
 *
 * Computer Science 50
 * Problem Set 4
 *
 * Recovers JPEGs from a forensic image.
 */

 //0xff 0xd8 0xff 0xe0
 //0xff 0xd8 0xff 0xe1

#define BLOCK 512
#define START1END 0xe0
#define START2END 0xe1

#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void namer();

//sets the begins or jpgs
uint8_t checkjpg1[4] = {0xff, 0xd8, 0xff, 0xe0};
uint8_t checkjpg2[4] = {0xff, 0xd8, 0xff, 0xe1};

//making variables
int found = 0; 
char title[BLOCK];
FILE* img;
int ifopen = 1;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //opening file
    FILE* inptr = fopen("card.raw", "r");
    //checking if file opening failed
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        return 2;
    }

    //making buffer
    unsigned char buffer[BLOCK];

    //going through the file
    while(fread(&buffer,sizeof(char),BLOCK,inptr) == BLOCK)
    {
         //checking if begin == the possible begin of jpg    
         if ((buffer[0] == checkjpg1[0] && buffer[1] == checkjpg1[1] && buffer[2] == checkjpg1[2]) && 
         (buffer[3] == checkjpg1[3] || buffer[3] == checkjpg2[3]))
         {
            //if a jpg is not open
            if (ifopen == 1)
            {
                //make one
                found+=1;
                namer(&found,&title);
                do 
                {
                    img = fopen(title,"a");
                }
                while (img == NULL);
                if(buffer[3] == checkjpg1[3])
                {
                    fwrite(&checkjpg1,sizeof(uint8_t),8,img);
                }

            }
            else//else
            {
                //end the one and open new one
                fclose(img);
                found +=1;
                namer(&found,&title);
                do 
                {
                    img = fopen(title,"a");
                }
                while (img == NULL);
                if(buffer[3] == checkjpg1[3])
                {
                    fwrite(&checkjpg2,sizeof(uint8_t),8,img);
                }
            }
         }
         else if (img != NULL)
         {
            fwrite(buffer,sizeof(char),BLOCK,img);
         }
     }

    fclose(inptr);
}





void namer(int* found,char* title)
{   
    if (*found > 9)
    {
        sprintf(title,"0%d.jpg",*found);
    }
    else
    {
        sprintf(title,"00%d.jpg",*found);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://www.colosseumbuilders.com/sourcecode/imagelib403.zip) contains JPEG decoding software and a utility to print out the structure of a JPEG image. You should run such a dumping program over your JPEG stream to see what you actually have.

Comment: I actually am doing this for a class, and I am actually trying to get a JPG.

Comment: That will tell you if you actually ARE getting a JPEG and what you're getting if you're not.